# Как присвоить значение для его использования в sqlite python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

***Вот кусок кода:***

```
myid = 77777777
c.execute('''
             UPDATE users
             SET balance = 10000
             WHERE user_id = myid
                ''')
```

***Но он видит это как колонку и выдает ошибку:***

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: myid
```

***Как избежать этого и использовать myid?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на варианты форматирования строк. Например, [здесь](https://python-scripts.com/string-formatting).

Ваш код можно поправить следующим образом.

```
id = 77777777
c.execute('UPDATE users SET balance = 10000 WHERE user_id = {0}'.format(id))
# c.execute(f'UPDATE users SET balance = 10000 WHERE user_id = {id}')
```

Comment: Вот такая ошибка: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "<": syntax error

Comment: а, всё исправил, в коде сам напортачил, спасибо - работает!